# I found the logic to solve the problem of Breaking Record but I am facing some problem with the code output

Tags: javascript, function

```
var scores = [10, 5, 20, 20, 4, 5, 2, 25, 1];
function breakingRecords(scores) {
  const array = scores;
  var count = 0;
  var count1 = 0;
  var temp = array[0];
  var temp1 = array[0];
  var i, j;

  function HP(array) {
    var b = array;

    for (i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
      if (temp > b[i]) {
        b.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      } else {
        temp = b[i];
      }
    }
    const ar = b.filter((item, index) => b.indexOf(item) === index);
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
      if (ar[0] < ar[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  const a1 = HP(array);

  function LP(array) {
    var a = array;

    for (j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (temp1 < a[j]) {
        a.splice(j, 1);
        j--;
      } else {
        temp1 = a[j];
      }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (a[0] > a[j]) {
        count1++;
      }
    }
    return count1;
  }
  const b1 = LP(array);

  const arr = [b1, a1];
  return arr;
}

const ans = breakingRecords(scores);
console.log(ans);
```

`I am trying to solve the problem but not getting the expected output. And the Logic works the function HP and LP while running separately giving the expected output. when the whole program is executed it's not working as expected. Kindly point out what is wrong with the coding. Thank you

input :
9
10 5 20 20 4 5 2 25 1

expected output :

2 4

The first output is high peak ex:(20,25);     =2
The second output is low peak ex:(5,4,2,1);   =4
`

Comment: You probably need to make `temp` and `temp1` local variables to `HP` and `LP` (better solution), or reinitialise them before calling `LP`.

Comment: `var b = array;` doesn't copy the array, `b` and `array` refer to the exact same array, therefore any modifications to `b` will change `array`, therefore `LP` will NOT get the full `array` since you `b.splice`d it several times.... try `var b = array.slice();` and `var a = array.slice();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired output just by changing the assigning of `array` to `a` & `b` like below (assign `[...array]` to create a separate array instead of `array` which will pass the value by reference)

```js
var scores = [10, 5, 20, 20, 4, 5, 2, 25, 1];
function breakingRecords(scores) {
  const array = scores;
  var count = 0;
  var count1 = 0;
  var temp = array[0];
  var temp1 = array[0];
  var i, j;

  function HP(array) {
    var b = [...array];

    for (i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
      if (temp > b[i]) {
        b.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      } else {
        temp = b[i];
      }
    }
    const ar = b.filter((item, index) => b.indexOf(item) === index);
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
      if (ar[0] < ar[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  const a1 = HP(array);

  function LP(array) {
    var a = [...array];

    for (j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (temp1 < a[j]) {
        a.splice(j, 1);
        j--;
      } else {
        temp1 = a[j];
      }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (a[0] > a[j]) {
        count1++;
      }
    }
    return count1;
  }
  const b1 = LP(array);

  const arr = [a1, b1];
  return arr;
}

const ans = breakingRecords(scores);
console.log(ans);
```